# Trouble with using roscpp and mavros api to integrate pixhawk with Jetson

Tags: ros, roscpp, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to Integrate pixhawk with Nvidia Jetson TK1.
I was able to use ROS/Mavros and communicate with pixhawk by ros commands.
Now I'm trying to use roscpp and mavros C++ api to communicate with pixhawk by C++ development on Jetson.
I was able to run hello world program by following this tutorial http://jbohren.com/articles/roscpp-hello-world/

Now, I'm trying to use it and mavros api to send arming commands to pixhawk.
I modified it this way and compiled the program.

// Include the ROS C++ APIs

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <mavros/mavros.h>
#include <mavros/CommandBool.h>
#include <mavros/mavros_plugin.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace mavros;
using namespace mavplugin;

// Standard C++ entry point
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Announce this program to the ROS master as a "node" called "hello_world_node"
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mavros");
  // Start the node resource managers (communication, time, etc)
  ros::start();
  // Broadcast a simple log message
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hello, world!");
  //Create Request and Response structures for Arming service
  CommandBool::Request arm_req;//=new CommandBool::Request<std::Allocator<void>>();
  arm_req.value=1;
  CommandBool::Response arm_res;//=new CommandBool::Response();
  //Send arming command to master node
  bool result=mavplugin::CommandPlugin::arming_cb(&arm_req, &arm_res);
  // Process ROS callbacks until receiving a SIGINT (ctrl-c)
  ros::spin();
  // Stop the node's resources
  ros::shutdown();
  // Exit tranquilly
  return 0;
}
```

I got the following error message after compiling this:

```
sample.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
sample.cpp:28:26: error: ‘mavplugin::CommandPlugin’ has not been declared
   bool result=mavplugin::CommandPlugin::arming_cb(&arm_req, &arm_res);
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to proceed?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202864/trouble-with-using-roscpp-and-mavros-api-to-integrate-pixhawk-with-jetson/) by [the_reddevil](https://answers.ros.org/users/21603/the_reddevil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/33144/cong/) on 2018-01-04**:
Can you tell how to use ROS/Mavros and communicate with pixhawk by ros commands?
Email:iwangcong@outlook.com
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You used wrong namespace.

`mavplugin` is for plugins only, do not include it in your nodes.
Also you don't need pluginlib.

Second: ros::init(), "mavros" taken by `mavros_node`!

Third: you should use ros services! Calling plugin class methods completely wrong.

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1